# Vector subscript out of range error occurs when I run an official OpenCV sample

Tags: c++, opencv, sift, surf

I'm learning OpenCV and I have tried running [this sample](http://codepad.org/LtydHOQu) which comes from opencv official samples. This sample uses SURF to find a known object. I created a VS2010 project and added the following to the project:

```
opencv_core231.lib opencv_highgui231.lib opencv_features2d231.lib
opencv_video231.lib
```

I can compile the project successfully. However, when I run it I receive the following error:

```
Expression: vector subscript out of range
```

I debugged the program and found out the error occurs on lin e60: `double dist = matches[i].distance`. I don't understand why I am getting the error.  Can enyone help me correct this?

Comment: are you compiling for 64-bit or 32-bit, and are you in debug or release mode?

Comment: @Kevin It's for 32bit and error occurs when I use ctrl+F5. I think it's release mode, isn't it? I don't add debug library into this project.

Comment: @setevenYANG : could you please try to display the size f the 'matches' array and the value of 'i' when the error happens ?

Comment: @SkippyFastol oops! sizeof matches is 0 and i is 0 too, error happens in the first loop. But why matches has no element? I use two pictures  and they are generated by rotating one same picture with different angles, is this wrong?

Comment: @Kevin I was wrong. I did not  understand two modes very well. I check it this morning. Now I'm sure I'm in debug mode. Also, I put some other libraries into this project and it now behaves more reasonable. But problem occurs changes to "bad memory reading"(LINE 60). The matches has more than 1000000 elements, is that normal?